# Different behavior for overflow property between IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

The main problem is that, when I put an asp control in the bottom right corner of a div, in chrome it will cause overflow but in IE will not.
I set the overflow property to auto.
I found temper solution which is to delaying set overflow property to auto about 5 second, this time is for finish rendering the control.
I try to set overflow property to auto at the end of ready function but it dose not work, because at this point the control stile loading its data.
this is my code at first

```
<div class="layer-wrapper" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto; position:absolute;">
```

then I removed overflow property and add this function at the end of ready function

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        $(".layer-wrapper").css('overflow', 'auto');
    }, 5000);
```

now the problem solve but I think this is not the best solution.

can anyone you help.

Comment: Help with what? You've given no code.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet or more details on it please

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? and which IE are you using? This is neccessary info since they can all give different results

Comment: I am using IE 11, but I dont know how to create a jsfiddle @VRC

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net You can create one. When you are done just press save and it generates an url for you which you can post here. There are 4 windows which 3 of them you can edit. HTML, Javascript and CSS. the 4th is the result when you press run to run the 3 windows. Left you can include the jquery library

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell without code.

So are you saying if your "layer-wrapper" div had a red background applied it doesn't fill the screen? Which is the problem as you see it, chrome causing overflow or IE not causing overflow?

You could try putting left and top attributes on your layer-wrapper div. You could try putting position relative on the layer-wrapper div instead of position absolute. Clear:both on the input may help as it does with float scenarios. It all depends on the implementation. You def shouldn't need js to solve this. Fiddle pls.